# do we require any Antivirus to be install in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: antivirus

Does require antivirus for Ubuntu 13.04, if yes then what is the anti-virus should be install in Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is no, unless you need virus protection for Windows machines. Virus and other malware don't tend to bother to target Linux.

Comment: What he said, plus you are safe until you give a "virus" permission to the filesystem.

Comment: Also, if you use [WINE](http://www.winehq.com/), Windows-based viruses might be able to isnfect Wine. Therefore, Wine users should have an anti-virus installed.

Comment: Infected wine can only touch wine files right?